# C++ boost library - Properly handle date sequence memory allocation error

Tags: c++, memory, boost

I have some code that make use of the boost library in C++, in particular the date class in boost library.

Unfortunately, the function is giving me some memory allocation error, but I do not get to see the exact dates in the date sequence that caused such a failure nor the actual reason why (was it an index out of bound or was it just an error that it could not parse the date properly from an int or was it a casting error?)

I am just wondering rather than say catch (...), if there is a better way for me to catch the error and output some debug information that might be useful to me?

Thanks!

Comment: How about don't catch it all and load your program inside a debugger? If you don't know how to use a debugger, lerning might be your best next step ;)

Comment: Catching the error is likely to supress information, not display it. I agree with Troy, let you program crash and then use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug a rogue exception is to not catch it and let your program crash while loaded in a debugger.

If you've never used a debugger, it might be a good time to learn.

Comment: I am using a debugger except the stack trace is not giving me too much useful info.